# Using css files in wagtail (django based CMS)

Tags: django, wagtail

I stuck on REALLY simple thing. But I can't spot what I am doing wrong - I just want to write some CSS for my template. Here's my "gallery" app tree (both of css files contain `body{background-color: #000;}` to just test if it work):

```
gallery
 -blah blah
 -static
   -css
     -wagtail_gallery.css
     -wagtail_gallery0.css
 -blah blah
```

template:

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}

{% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}
<link href="{% static 'css/wagtail_galery.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

{% block body_class %}template-blogindexpage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>

    <div class="intro">{{ page.intro|richtext }}</div>

    {% for subpage in gallery_subpages %}
      {% with subpage=subpage.specific %}
          <a href="{% pageurl subpage %}">
            {% with subpage.main_image as main_image %}

                <!-- This line creates image that links to subpage -->
                {% if main_image %}{% image main_image original %}{% endif %}

            {% endwith %}
          </a>
      {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

When I opened source, to see what is going on, i saw this link in head section: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/wagtail_gallery.css">`. When I open it its blank (independly on existance of `wagtail_gallery.css`).

When I go to `http://localhost:8000/static/css/wagtail_galery0.css`  in browser it shows me excepted content.

Now, my questions are - How can I use `wagtail_gallery.css` in template, and how can I import custom css (like `wagtail_gallery0.css`) file to wagtail template?

Sorry if I missed something obvious in this issue, but I am new in wagtail CMS. Also, sorry if I missed some "l" in "gallery" somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Wagtail is just Django it uses [Django static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/). It's hard to tell exactly what's going on but I suspect that your "static" directory is maybe one level too high. It should be like this...

```
ProjectFolder    
  -YourAppFolder
    -static
      -wagtail_gallery.css
```

Try moving the static folder into "blah blah" folder? Also make sure you have the correct imports from the linked docs above and that the App is actually being imported in you base settings.

Finally in your template you'll need to be linking to the correct file. Something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/wagtail_gallery.css' %}">
```

Comment: It isnt issue with wrong dictionary. Thanks for your answer anyway. But I have also some question - where in template should I import css like you shown?

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Tried it locally and it seems to be working correctly for me. You have some confusing names but, when I go to the homepage I get a stylesheet from your base app /static/css/wagtail_galery.css (notice the single L in gallery). When I hit /gallery/ I get the stylesheets from both apps: /static/css/wagtail_galery.css AND /static/css/wagtail_gallery.css This is because you have different links in your base.html and the extra_css in the gallery template. I would get rid of the css file in /gallery/ and only use the base app one from wagtail_galery...

Comment: Ok, I find it. I won't write my own answer. I was doing everything good, but i forgot about django problems with caching static files - I had to just reset server, then everything worked as I excepted.